# How can we get the running state of a PWM channel in STM32?

Tags: stm32, pwm

In my code I use HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT to start a PWM generation and HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop to stop the PWM train. I need to check whether PWM is stopped or not at some part of the code.

How can that be implemented?

Comment: Which STM32 exactly? The timer peripherals vary between parts, and there are also multiple versions of the timer that can be found within a single part.

Comment: Using now Nucleo F303K8. https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/nucleo-f303k8.pdf

Comment: And which of the timers? The STM32F303K8 has about ten of them and they all have different capabilities.

Comment: I use TIM1 and TIM3 to generate two PWM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the CEN bit in the timer's CR1 register. The HAL sets it when the timer is enabled in PWM mode, and clears it again when all PWM channels on that timer have been disabled (with `HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop`).

[Reference manual for your microcontroller](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0316-stm32f303xbcde-stm32f303x68-stm32f328x8-stm32f358xc-stm32f398xe-advanced-armbased-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (see section 20, Advanced Control Timers)

Comment: By disabled do you mean HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop  ?

Comment: Yes, HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop will clear CR1->CEN. HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(_IT) will set it.

Comment: How would I read that bit? into an integer(0 or 1)? Im a bit in a hurry. TIM_CR1_CEN is the mask and TIM1->CR1  accesses the register. Should I write TIM1->CR1 and ? I need to read CEN somehow as you said. My question was about the implementation actually.

Comment: How can we read the CEN bit I mean? Not setting but reading it.

Comment: is it like int x = TIM_CR1_CEN;?

Comment: Or check_bit = TIM1->CR1 & TIM_CR1_CEN; ?

Comment: This assumes the clock to the timer is enabled no? One hackey but reliable way to check  it is running is to sample htim1.Instance->CNT twice and see if they are different. Assuming the ARR is sufficiently large that the check can never loop, this lets you know for absolute certain that it is counting.

Comment: The HAL always sets and clears the CEN bit, regardless of whether the clock to the timer is enabled or not, so it doesn't make a difference here. You can read the bit as `TIMn->CR1 & TIM_CR1_CEN`, as you already said.

Comment: @JonathanS. I also opened another question about an issue on the same MCU https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/645056/problem-with-pwm-generation-waveform-in-stm32

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are many ways to check for hardware status, using registers and what not. But I always prefer simple straightforward solutions.

In this case, since you are the one doing starting/stopping of the PWM generation, why don't you simply declare status flag and set/reset it in your own Start() Stop() functions right after calling HAL (assuming HAL returned HAL_OK, of course)?

Then you can check this flag either directly or via another function of your own. The benefit of this approach is complete transparency and portability.